# Want to know the Values size for Galxy S

Tags: android, textview

I am making an application in which I am facing a lot of difficulties while dealing with text sizes.

I have made these values folders and their respective String/text sizes in between :

1. values      FOR HDPI
2. values-ldpi For LDPI
3. values-mdpi  For MDPI
4. values-sw360dp For S3

**Now the problem is when I am using GALAXY S device ( Samsung ) it is taking very large font size and is not taking from HDPI folder. I just wanted to know which Values Galaxy S is taking from.**

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Galaxy S are you using?

Comment: **"values FOR HDPI"** - No, the `values` folder is used for the 'base-line' screen model, i.e., mdpi and is effectively the same as values-mdpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check screen size by below method and try to set values size dynamically.

```
private void checkScreenSize()
{
    int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

    switch(screenSize) 
    {
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
            Toast.makeText(this, " Xlarge screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Normal screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           // normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

            break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Small screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is neither xlarge,large,normal nor small" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

For more info check [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can install this app on your device, which provides all the device related information including the display resolution.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.developertools